# Symfony autoloading a namespace on every controller

Tags: php, namespaces, components, symfony

I have already seen that there is an autoload_namespace.php file in Symfony but I cant seem to get it to work.

I want to autoload the: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session namespace.

Here is the autoload_namespace.php so far

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'SensioLabs\\Security' => array($vendorDir . '/sensiolabs/security-checker'),
    'Psr\\Log\\' => array($vendorDir . '/psr/log'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
    //this is the session namespace i want to auto include
    'Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Session\\Session\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.php')
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include some code/description of what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have just updated the post now with the autoload_namespace

Comment: Are you trying to add stuff directly to the autoload_namespace.php?  That won't end well.

Comment: I was trying to generate it from the composer but I didn't know how to do the session component @Cerad

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do.  composer require symfony/http-foundation will take care of everything. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#installation.  If you really think you need more then you would edit the autoload section in composer.json.